# ActionScript Defining a Static Constant Array

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, static, constants

is it not possible to define a static const array?  i would like to have an optional parameter to a function that is an array of colors,

```
private static const DEFAULT_COLORS:Array = new Array(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF);

public function myConstructor(colorsArray:Array = DEFAULT_COLORS)
{
}
```

i know i can use ...args but i actually wanting to supply the constructor with 2 separate arrays as option arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, but you could this to simulate this behaviour:

```
private static const DEFAULT_COLORS:Array = new Array(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF);

public function myConstructor(colorsArray:Array = null)
{
    colorsArray = colorsArray ? colorsArray : DEFAULT_COLORS;
}
```

This will not work if your function is coded in a way such that null could be a valid value (to signal some condition, for instance), but probably that's not the case here.

**Edit**

If you plan to write to colorsArray in myConstructor, it would be wise to make a copy of DEFAULT_COLORS here:

```
colorsArray = colorsArray ? colorsArray : DEFAULT_COLORS.slice();
```

The reference to the DEFAULT_COLORS Array is constant, but its contents are not, so you could accidentally change your default values.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  works great.  however, can you explain how i might accidentally change the default colors by not making a copy of the array?  i'm not quite following what you mean.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978. Sure. If you call the function with no parameters (or null) `colorsArray` will be a reference to `DEFAULT_COLORS`. I.e. it will give access to the same object. Then, if at some point in your function you do something like `colorsArray[0] = 0xffcc99;` or `colorsArray.splice(0,1);` or anything that modifies `colorsArray`, you will be changing the contents of `DEFAULT_COLORS`, probably without intending to do so. This is because colorsArray will be a reference to the same object that the `DEFAULT_COLORS` const references. Making a copy, that can't possibly happen.